# How can I use a sed regex to extract HTML and modify a timestamp?

Tags: html, regex, sed

Using curl + grep I get the following output:

```
<h3>Serial ID: L322607B2411012</h3>
<span>felipea</span>
<span>2015-10-05 20:06:43 UTC</span>
```

I'm new on sed-stuff and I want to use sed in order to get just the following output:

```
L322607B2411012
felipea
20:06:43
```

I wrote the following regex in order to reach the result:

```
/<|>|h3|/|span| UTC|.......... /g
```

Tested on http://www.regexr.com/ with the text:

```
<h3>Serial ID: L322607B2411012</h3>
<span>felipea</span>
<span>2015-10-05 20:06:43 UTC</span>
<h3>Serial ID: L322607B2411135</h3>
<span>tressino</span>
<span>2015-10-05 19:57:10 UTC</span>
```

And it highlighted the matches as needed (image: http://snag.gy/0ge60.jpg), but it doesn't work when I do the real test, follow the command:

```
curl internalURL | egrep -i '(utc|Serial ID:|tressino|felipea)' | sed 's/<|>|h3|/|span| UTC|.......... /g'
```

The command above returns the normal output, same as without sed+regex.

Escaping the slash it returns the following error:

```
sed 's/<|>|h3|\/|span| UTC|.......... /g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unterminated `s' command
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does it not work? What happens?

Comment: You need to escape the slash: `\/`. Otherwise the pattern ends early.

Comment: It does nothing, the output is exactly the same as without sed+regex. If I use sed -r instead of just sed it returns the following output:
|span| UTC|.......... |span| UTC|.......... |span| UTC|.......... S|span| UTC|.......... e|span| UTC|.......... r|span| UTC|.......... i|span| UTC|.......... a|span| UTC|.......... l|span| UTC|..........  |span| UTC|.......... I|span| UTC|.......... D|span| UTC|.......... :|span| UTC|..........  |span| UTC|.......... L|span| UTC|.......... and so on

Comment: Escaping the slash as @lenz said it returns the following error: sed 's/<|>|h3|\/|span| UTC|.......... /g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Oh, is this your actual regex, not just some kind of abbreviation notation?

Comment: @lenz, exactly, this is my regex. As I said, it is the first time I'm using sed and REGEX, so I'm probably doing something wrong :S

Comment: This is not well-formed HTML or XHTML. Use XPath to parse your real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the regex as follows:

```
sed 's/<|>|h3|\/|span| UTC//g'
```

The substution command is `s/.../.../`, where the first ellipsis (`...`) is the pattern and the second one is the replacement.

Edit: As you are actually asking what's going wrong, here's an explanation: In the regex substitution `s/<|>|h3|/|span| UTC|.......... /g`, the pattern is `<|>|h3|`, ie. `<`, `>`, `h3` or nothing. The replacement is `|span| UTC|..........`, which is what you get all over with `-r` option.

Comment: Perfect. I just added the rest of the strings it needs to remove and it worked:  sed -r 's/<|>|h3|\/|span|ID: | UTC|.......... //g'

Comment: @anubhava: Yes, but the dots removed this outputs as well :)

Comment: Wow what a way to remove undesired string. Do you realize what all `......` can remove in regex?

Comment: @anubhava: As far as I understood it will match any string that has the same length of the dots, in this case (`.......... `) it will match 10 consecutive chars with a space at the end after it replace every other patterns the regex has. Don't know if I could explain it well...

Comment: @ZeroNegative You explained it pretty well. The thing is that it might match things it shouldn't if you don't know what curl will give you as input.

Answer (score 0):

You will be better off using this simple `awk` command to get your text in between `h3` and `span` tags:

```
awk -F '</?(span|h3)>' '{print $2}' file
Serial ID: L322607B2411012
felipea
2015-10-05 20:06:43 UTC
Serial ID: L322607B2411135
tressino
2015-10-05 19:57:10 UTC
```

PS: Pipe to another to get your desired output:

```
awk -F '</?(span|h3)>' '{print $2}' file | awk '/ID:/{print $3;next} / UTC/{print $2;next} 1'
L322607B2411012
felipea
20:06:43
L322607B2411135
tressino
19:57:10
```

Though keep in mind that `awk/sed/grep` etc are not the best tools to parse HTML text.

Answer (score 0):

### TL; DR

Don't parse HTML with regular expressions. Use a tool that supports XPath, such as [XmlStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php).

### Example Using XmlStarlet

Given well-formed input such as:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h3>Serial ID: L322607B2411012</h3>
    <span>felipea</span>
    <span>2015-10-05 20:06:43 UTC</span>
    <h3>Serial ID: L322607B2411135</h3>
    <span>tressino</span>
    <span>2015-10-05 19:57:10 UTC</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can use XPath to extract the text nodes you want. For example:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//h3/text() | //span/text()' -n /tmp/foo.html
Serial ID: L322607B2411012
felipea
2015-10-05 20:06:43 UTC
Serial ID: L322607B2411135
tressino
2015-10-05 19:57:10 UTC
```

You can then munge your timestamps and break your output into records with sed or awk. As an example, consider this one-liner:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//h3/text() | //span/text()' -n /tmp/foo.html |
    awk '/UTC$/ {print $2 "\n"; next}; {print}'
Serial ID: L322607B2411012
felipea
20:06:43

Serial ID: L322607B2411135
tressino
19:57:10
```